# GLSL compiler optimizations lead to incorrect behavior with floating point operations

Tags: android, opengl-es, glsl, glsles

I am part of a team writing an Android application using OpenGL. We have a good bit of shader code emulating double-precision math using floats. (Specifically we implemented the algorithms in Andrew Thall's [Extended-Precision Floating-Point Numbers for GPU Computation](http://andrewthall.org/papers/df64_qf128.pdf).) It works well in the DirectX version of the application, but I've found that on Android, the GLSL compiler is optimizing some of the code in such a way that, algebraically, behavior should be preserved, but in reality it changes behavior because the optimizations are throwing away floating point error. For example, in the following:

```
vec2 add(float a, float b) {
    float sum = a + b;
    float err = b - (sum - a);
    return vec2(sum, err);
}
```

the error value e gets simplified to 0 by the compiler since that's true algebraically, but of course that is not always the case when floating point error is taken into account.

I tried "#pragma optimize (off)", but it's not standard and had no effect. The only hack I've found that works is to create a "zero" uniform float that remains set to 0 and add that to the offending values in strategic places, so a working version of the above function would be:

```
vec2 add(float a, float b) {
    float sum = a + b;
    sum += zero;
    float err = b - (sum - a);
    return vec2(sum, err);
}
```

This is obviously not ideal. 1) It's a PITA to track down where this is necessary, and 2) it's compiler dependent. Another compiler may not need it, and another one could conceivably optimize the *e* value down to *zero*. Is there a "correct" way to solve this problem and make sure the GLSL compiler doesn't optimize away actual behavior?

## Edit:

While the technical answer looks to remain "no", I've found a better work-around and wanted to document it here. The "zero" uniform method did indeed start to fail with more complicated expressions/chained operations. The workaround I found was to create two functions for addition and subtraction:

```
float plus_frc(float a, float b) {
    return mix(a, a + b, b != 0);
}

float minus_frc(float a, float b) {
    return mix(0, a - b, a != b);
}
```

(The "frc" stands for both "force" and "farce", because you're forcing the operation, but the necessity is idiotic.) These replicate the functionality of (a + b) and (a - b), respectively, but in a way that the compiler shouldn't be able to optimize away, doesn't use branching and uses a [fast builtin](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/GLSL_Optimizations#Linear_Interpolation) to do the work. So the above error-preserving "add" function becomes:

```
vec2 add(float a, float b) {
    float sum = plus_frc(a, b);
    float err = b - (sum - a);
    return vec2(sum, err);
}
```

Note that we do not *always* need to use our "frc" functions (e.g. the equation to find err), but only in places where the compiler could have done breaking optimizations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. There is no binding way to control optimizations in GLSL. If the compiler feels that it's reasonable to assume that your error term is zero, then it will be zero.